# SQL Select two max rows from same table and joining with third table

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group, sql-view

Two tables in the mix:

items

```
| item_id | user_id | data |
----------------------------
| 10       | 100    | A    |
| 11       | 100    | C    |
| 12       | 101    | E    |
| 13       | 101    | G    |
```

item_detail

```
| id | item_id | ignore | detail1 | detail2 | detail3 | detail4 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 10      |   0    |   h1    |   h2    |  h3     |  h4     |
| 2  | 10      |   0    |   g1    |   g2    |  g3     |  g4     |
| 3  | 10      |   1    |   f1    |   f2    |  f3     |  f4     |
| 4  | 11      |   0    |   e1    |   e2    |  e3     |  e4     |
| 5  | 11      |   0    |   d1    |   d2    |  d3     |  d4     |
| 6  | 11      |   1    |   c1    |   c2    |  c3     |  c4     |
| 7  | 12      |   0    |   b1    |   b2    |  b3     |  b4     |
| 8  | 13      |   0    |   a1    |   a2    |  a3     |  a4     |
```

**I need to find detail1,detail2 from MAX id of item_detail by item_id AND the detail3,detail4 of MAX NON IGNORED ID of item_detail by item_id, and show with item line.**
Expected result:

```
| item_id | user_id | data | detail1 | detail2 | detail3 | detail4 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 10      | 100     | A    |   f1    | f2      | g3      | g4      |       
| 11      | 100     | C    |   c1    | c2      | d3      | d4      |
| 12      | 101     | E    |   b1    | b2      | b3      | b4      |
| 13      | 101     | G    |   a1    | a2      | a3      | a4      |
```

Here is SQLFiddle with these data sets: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52839
Any takers? Your input is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your sample data accordingly to your edit too.

Comment: Update your example accordingly (and I hope we're not talking about comma-separated values here !!?!?)

Comment: Edited the question as you asked. No CSVs... Also added a fiddle.
Please note, the sort is by the id to get the MAX, not the detail. Also, I can't use the first solution (with inner select) because I need this as a view which will not allow that. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is going to be to use `group_concat()` with `substring_index()`:

```
select i.item_id, i.user_id, i.data,
       substring_index(group_concat(id.detail order by id.id desc), ',', 1
                      ) as last_detail,
       substring_index(group_concat(case when id.ignored = 0 then id.detail1 end order by id.id desc), ',', 1
                      ) as last_non_ignored_detail1
       substring_index(group_concat(case when id.ignored = 0 then id.detail2 end order by id.id desc), ',', 1
                      ) as last_non_ignored_detail2
       substring_index(group_concat(case when id.ignored = 0 then id.detail3 end order by id.id desc), ',', 1
                      ) as last_non_ignored_detail3
       substring_index(group_concat(case when id.ignored = 0 then id.detail4 end order by id.id desc), ',', 1
                      ) as last_non_ignored_detail4
  from items i join
       item_detail id
       on i.item_id = id.item_id
 group by i.item_id;
```

Comment: I am going to benchmark it right now, thanks for the quick response. In order to simplify the question I removed few extra "detail" columns from item_detail. can u provide another answer with solution to that?.

Comment: You can handle them the same way.

Comment: Do I add more substring_index in the select? Can you edit your reply so it reflects my EDIT? your solution seems to be the right one, just need this last detail before I close. Thx.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is perfect. Do I need to worry about performance with 50,000 and 10 columns usings ubstring_index(group_concat(case perform on each column?

Comment: @Yaniv . . . Depends on your expectations for performance.  If the tables are indexed on the `join` columns, then this will take about as long as any `group by` query -- probably a few seconds.

Comment: Looking at the execution plans of both, I'm willing to bet that the second option in Strawberry's answer is more efficient than this answer. And proves that this one isn't the 'easiest way'.

Comment: @Arwin . . . The second answer gets the max of `detailed`.  It doesn't get the value of `detailed` for the max of `id`.  It does something different.

Comment: Ah, how did I miss that. Thanks, there's apparently a good reason for why your reputation is so high ... ;)

Answer (score 5):

How about...

```
SELECT i.* 
     , x.detail last_detail
     , y.detail last_non_ignored_detail
  FROM items i
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT a.* 
         FROM item_detail a 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT item_id
                  , MAX(id) max_id 
               FROM item_detail 
              GROUP 
                 BY item_id
            ) b 
           ON b.item_id = a.item_id 
          AND b.max_id = a.id
     ) x
    ON x.item_id = i.item_id
  LEFT
  JOIN  
     ( SELECT a.* 
         FROM item_detail a 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT item_id
                  , MAX(id) max_id 
               FROM item_detail
              WHERE ignored = 0
              GROUP 
                 BY item_id
            ) b 
           ON b.item_id = a.item_id 
          AND b.max_id = a.id
     ) y
    ON y.item_id = i.item_id;
```

... or something like that.

Oh, silly me...

```
SELECT i.*
     , MAX(d.detail) x
     , MAX(CASE WHEN d.ignored = 0 THEN d.detail END) y
  FROM items i 
  JOIN item_detail d 
    ON d.item_id = i.item_id 
 GROUP  
    BY item_id;
```

Note that IGNORE is a reserved word, so I changed it. (I took the liberty of changing it Gordon's answer too!)

Comment: Your edit was where I was going as well, but I didn't know that you could do a CASE WHEN in a MAX, neat! I'm going to be bold, just to try edit for once, and remove your wrong answer and add the fiddle. Hope that's ok!

Comment: Would you ever use the first instead of the second? In this age of information overlead, hiding a great, compact, readable answer behind a long, unnecesarily complicated one is almost as wrong as a wrong answer. ;) If you think the first answer is important as well, why not post it separately?

Comment: Ah, and then performance rears its ugly head! If the first query is faster (not tested) then that should override all other concerns!

Comment: No, speed does not always win. The more elegant solution is often also easier to maintain, prevent mistakes, etc. ;) But it's a non-discussion. I gave you a fiddle for the table, so you can look at the execution plan, which clearly shows that the second solution is far superior. If you post your other answer separately, you can add a fiddle to that too. See how many votes the other one gets ... :)

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for nitpicking but the query matches the "detail" field which is arbitrary, I am looking for MAX of ID because it's the last line inserted. Also, if you could address the EDIT in my question it would be great.